# jQuery $.post returns arrow with variable

Tags: javascript, php, debugging

The image below shows a debugging of a function in Chrome DevTools:

[image]

I realized that the data returned from the PHP file always has an arrow before the string as seen in the above. What causes this?

This poses a big issue for me. For example when comparing the string. Whenever I use

```
if(data == "success")
```

the statement in that block won't run because it would be false. The code I use in the PHP file is:

```
echo 'success';
```

Answer (score 0):

That value is coming from the server. You need to fix the the code there so that it generates the correct response. It's likely you have some line breaks at the beginning of the PHP file you're calling which should be removed.

That said, you can trim whitespace from the response in JS:

```
if (data.trim() == 'success')
```

I would also suggest you amend your server code so that you return something other than plain text, because, as you've seen, text can easily be affected by whitespace.

Try returning JSON instead. You can then use a boolean flag in the response and avoid the rather ugly comparison to an arbitrary string.

Answer (score 0):

Use `trim()` function

```
if (data.trim() === 'success')
```

Side note: Make habit of using `===` where possible

from API side, if accessible then check your return value

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning a string you may want to return a JSON object.
That will help you because like [Rory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45731150/6331369) said you can use booleans and also return multiple variables to your page. Accessing a JSON object with JS is easy.

In order to do that simply create a PHP array, add the data you want in it. Then when you want to return the array use [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to return a JSON representation of your array.

**PHP code (AJAX target file)**

```
$return = array(
  'status' => true
);

echo json_encode($return);
```

**JS (callback function)**

```
if(response.status) {
  console.log('success')
}
```

Comment: The callback function doesn't working for me. It only works whenever I put if(data.status!=true).

Comment: @DanielleS, can you take a screenshot of the returned object in the inspector, please?